# Linux: Replace first string in file with contents of other file containing quotes and slashes.

Tags: linux, sed

I have spent all day today trying to find a proper solution, but I am not able to. My problem:

I have an XML file with tags containing multiple of the same.
Example:

`<TASK INSTANCE />
<WORKFLOWLINK CONDITION=""/>
<WORKFLOWLINK CONDITION=""/>`

I want to add the contents of an other XML file before the first `<WORKFLOWLINK`. The issue I've ran into is that this file is full of double quotes and slashes. I've tried replacing them and escaping them, but to no avail.

My tries mainly culminated on something like:
`sed -e "0,/<WORKFLOWLINK/ /<WORKFLOWLINK/{ r ${filename}" -e "}" ${sourcefile}`

If this isn't clear enough I'll get the exact data so you can see.

Comment: Have you considered writing a template then running substitution on the template for inserts?

Comment: have you tried googling "parse xml with regex stack overflow"?

Comment: Whatever solution you end up with, it will **not** be `sed`. See [ask] then post a [mcve] including concise, **testable** sample input and expected output. Google "parse XML UNIX" to see what to tag your question with.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of sed:

```
sed -e "0,/<WORKFLOWLINK/{/<WORKFLOWLINK/{r ${sourcefile}" -e"}}"
```

The trick is to start a new "pattern/command" pair after your first address range condition `0,/<WORKFLOWLINK/`.
Two nested patterns/addresses are not understood, there must be a command after the first pattern. Using an additional pair of curlies `{}` does that for you.

Apart from the brain exercise to do it in sed, @EdMorton is right in  recommending to use an XML-processor. Also his request for an MCVE is appropriate. I had to do some guessing to see what you want and I hope I guessed right.
The mcve should at least have included

- the error message or problem description defining your problem
- the initialisation of your environment variables
- some sample input; not the original data

You surely would have had an answer earlier and (in case mine does not satisfy you) probably a better one by now.
So, before your next question, please take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

GNU sed version 4.2.1
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone,

Thank you for thinking with me, even if I apparently broke some rules.
I have figured out a solution, granted it is not as pretty as can be, but for a one time action it is good enough.

I have moved from a single command to a combination of first detecting the location I want to put my data:
`sed -e "0,/<WORKFLOWLINK/ s/<WORKFLOWLINK/@@MARKER@@\n\t<WORKFLOWLINK'"` which will put the marker string in the desired location.
After this I replace the marker with the contents of the file I have. I managed to make the individual statements working when I was trying to do it all in a single statement before, so I just execute them separately.
`sed -e "/@@MARKER@@/{r ${sourcefile}" -e 'd}'`